# Are these circular references of back references

Tags: php, circular-reference

I'm trying to understand if my approach to scoping/providing access from one class to another is correct.

I'm concerned my approach is creating circular references.

As the amount of classes increase, so does the amount of data output by var_dump, leading to overflows. However, it could be `var_dump` isn't correctly handling the pointers/references created?

So would this code create circular references or are they for want of a better word, backreferences?  And is this approach acceptable?

I'm concerned about circular references dude to the caveats outlined in [this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11856/whats-wrong-with-circular-references), especially the point:

> Circular class references create high coupling; both classes must be
>   recompiled every time either of them is changed

```
<?php 

class HomeController{

    public $AppleController     = null;
    public $OrangeController    = null;

    public function __construct(){
    }

    public function &InitAppleController(){
        if(!$this->AppleController){
            $this->AppleController = new AppleController($this); 
        }
        return $this->AppleController;
    }

    public function &InitOrangeController(){
        if(!$this->OrangeController){
            $this->OrangeController = new OrangeController($this); 
        }
        return $this->OrangeController;
    }
}


class BaseController{

    protected $HC;

    protected function __construct(&$HC){
        $this->HC = &$HC;
    }
}

class AppleController extends BaseController{

    public function __construct(&$HC){
        parent::__construct($oHC);
    }
}

class OrangeController extends BaseController{

    public function __construct(&$HC){
        parent::__construct($oHC);
    }
}



$oHC = new HomeController();
$oAppleController = &$oHC->InitAppleHandler();
$oOrangeController = &$oHC->InitOrangeController();

// now methods in OrangeController can access methods in AppleController without 
// having reference passed directly to the method that needs the scope
?>
```

Comment: Wouldn't you be getting an error about no argument being passed to the HomeController constructor?

Comment: sorry this is pseudo code I typed out for the question. It shouldn't have been there.

Comment: Also, you're calling `$oHC->InitAppleHandler()` (twice) but have defined `InitAppleController()` and `InitOrangeController()`  I understand that this may be "pseudo code", but it should still be relatively valid.  I'm also curious as to how closely this resembles your actual code (and therefore how representative it is of your problem) given these errors.

Comment: of course it should. Thanks for pointing out the typos! Since you understand the gist, can you provide any insight my question? Would be greatly appreciated. It represents the code well enough that the problem/concerns I'm interested to learn about should be pretty obvious.

Comment: I think the basic answer is yes, you are creating circular / recursive references.  I'm curious what version of PHP you are using though.  On 7.3, `var_dump()` recognizes this and does not attempt to recurse.  5.3 does this as well, but it seems to take a few levels for it to catch on, which could be problematic.  However, you should _not_ be using a version of PHP that old.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give a more explanatory/advanced answer than yes? I.e. How would you attempt to prevent this. Why does memory usage or cpu time not increase compared to if references passed to methods directly. I’m using 5.3. Sometimes it’s not possible to upgrade php and poses no risk to do so if not publicly accessible. Would also love to know how to test the point highlighted at bottom of answer. Even some information to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Upgrading from 5.3 isn't just about risk mitigation.  I addition to performance benefits, which you seem concerned about, there is a good deal of functionality that has been introduced since 5.3.  That said, I wouldn't want to go into what alternatives to your current code might be better without an intimate understanding of your application.  Obviously, that is not within the scope of SO's Q&A format.  There are also far smarter people than I that could probably give better insights.

Comment: Thanks for your time and insight Patrick is very much appreciated. After quite some research im wondering if an interface could help. Thanks again